# R read.csv "More columns than column names" error

Tags: r, import

I have a problem when importing `.csv` file into R. With my code:

```
t <- read.csv("C:\\N0_07312014.CSV", na.string=c("","null","NaN","X"),
          header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names=F)
```

R reports an error and does not do what I want:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

I guess the problem is because my data is not well formatted. I only need data from `[,1:32]`. All others should be deleted.

Data can be downloaded from:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86_a8ltyoL3VXJYM3NVdmNPMUU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks so much！

Comment: You cannot change the structure of an HTML file to be a CSV-formated file by just changing its file extension.

Comment: It's a CSV file. A wonky one, with 10 headers interspersed throughout, but it's a CSV file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's one wonky CSV file. Multiple headers tossed about (try pasting it to [CSV Fingerprint](http://setosa.io/csv-fingerprint/)) to see what I mean.

Since I don't know the data, it's impossible to be sure the following produces accurate results for you, but it involves using `readLines` and other R functions to pre-process the text:

```
# use readLines to get the data
dat <- readLines("N0_07312014.CSV")

# i had to do this to fix grep errors
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')

# filter out the repeating, and wonky headers
dat_2 <- grep("Node Name,RTC_date", dat, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)

# turn that vector into a text connection for read.csv
dat_3 <- read.csv(textConnection(paste0(dat_2, collapse="\n")),
                  header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(dat_3)
## 'data.frame':    308 obs. of  37 variables:
##  $ V1 : chr  "Node 0" "Node 0" "Node 0" "Node 0" ...
##  $ V2 : chr  "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" ...
##  $ V3 : chr  "08:58:18" "08:59:22" "08:59:37" "09:00:06" ...
##  $ V4 : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
## .. more
##  $ V36: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
##  $ V37: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...

# grab the headers
headers <- strsplit(dat[1], ",")[[1]]

# how many of them are there?
length(headers)
## [1] 32

# limit it to the 32 columns you want (Which matches)
dat_4 <- dat_3[,1:32]

# and add the headers
colnames(dat_4) <- headers

str(dat_4)
## 'data.frame':    308 obs. of  32 variables:
##  $ Node Name         : chr  "Node 0" "Node 0" "Node 0" "Node 0" ...
##  $ RTC_date          : chr  "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" "07/31/2014" ...
##  $ RTC_time          : chr  "08:58:18" "08:59:22" "08:59:37" "09:00:06" ...
##  $ N1 Bat (VDC)      : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
##  $ N1 Shinyei (ug/m3): chr  "" "" "0.23" "null" ...
##  $ N1 CC (ppb)       : chr  "" "" "null" "null" ...
##  $ N1 Aeroq (ppm)    : chr  "" "" "null" "null" ...
## ... continues
```

Comment: readlines + grep to filter is a good idea. I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 13):

Open the .csv as a text file (for example, use TextEdit on a Mac) and check to see if columns are being separated with commas.

csv is "comma separated vectors". For some reason when Excel saves my csv's it uses semicolons instead.

When opening your csv use:

```
read.csv("file_name.csv",sep=";")
```

Semi colon is just an example but as someone else previously suggested don't assume that because your csv looks good in Excel that it's so.

Comment: You just saved me!

Answer (score 5):

If you only need the  first 32 columns, and you know how many columns there are, you can set the other columns classes to NULL.

```
read.csv("C:\\N0_07312014.CSV", na.string=c("","null","NaN","X"),
      header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      colClasses=c(rep("character",32),rep("NULL",10)))
```

If you do not want to code up each colClass and you like the guesses `read.csv` then just save that csv and open it again.

Alternatively, you can skip the header and name the columns yourself and remove the misbehaved rows.

```
A<-data.frame(read.csv("N0_07312014.CSV",
                        header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                        colClasses=c(rep("character",32),rep("NULL",5)),
                        na.string=c("","null","NaN","X")))
Yournames<-as.character(A[1,])
names(A)<-Yournames
yourdata<-unique(A)[-1,]
```

The code above assumes you do not want any duplicate rows.  You can alternatively remove rows that have the first entry equal to the first column name, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Should be `colClasses=`, and the CSV file is really wonky. That particular method does not produce a viable data frame for that data.

Comment: Can you skip the header row?

Comment: The problem is there is not just a single header row, there are 10 interspersed throughout the whole file

Comment: Then remove them.  Presumably you do not want any duplicates.  You can use `unique` to remove duplicates.

Comment: It's not my data and that's what my code does. With your last revision, the poster can use the data once they remove the all `NA` columns.

Comment: Remember, the OP wanted to get past the error.  header=F does that.

Answer (score 1):

try read.table() instead of read.csv()

Comment: This is way better then other but how to tackle with null values in table, then?

Comment: i am not sure whether you mean this : df [is.na(df)] <- 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was using csv2 instead of csv.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Now solved.

Just use `header = FALSE`

```
read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE) -> mydata
```

Comment: That is only a solution as long as there is no header. If the first line of the csv contains column names, than those are added to the variables and not only have to be filtered out, but also makes it neccessary to correct the data type of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I opened my data in textfile and double expressions are separated by semicolons, you should replace them with a period

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error that was caused by multiple rows of meta data at the top of the file. I was able to use read.csv by doing skip= and skipping those rows.

`data <- read.csv('/blah.csv',skip=3)`

Answer (score -2):

```r
read.csv("file_name.csv", header=F)
```

Setting the HEADER to be FALSE will do the job perfectly for you...