# SparkR ERROR RBackendHandler: fitRModelFormula

Tags: r, apache-spark, linear-regression, sparkr

I was trying to do a linear regression with sparkR, starting from [this tutorial](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/05/generalized-linear-models-in-sparkr-and-r-formula-support-in-mllib.html).

I got 2 dataframe airlines and planes with some field for each one.

```
#read dataframe 
airlines <- read.df(sqlContext, path="/home/daniele/air.csv",source="com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

planes <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/daniele/plane.csv",source="com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

#join both on tailnum field
joined<-join(airlines,planes,airlines$tailnum==planes$tailnum)

#it show some result as expected 
showDF(select(training,"aircraft_type","DISTANCE","arr_delay","dep_delay"))

model <- glm(arr_delay ~ dep_delay + DISTANCE,family = "gaussian", data = joined)
```

On the last command I got this:

```
ERROR RBackendHandler: fitRModelFormula on [org.apache.spark.ml.api.r.SparkRWrappers failed
Errore in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse formula: m$arr_delay ~ m$dep_delay
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormulaParser$.parse(RFormulaParser.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula.hasIntercept(RFormula.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.api.r.SparkRWrappers$.fitRModelFormula(SparkRWrappers.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.api.r.SparkRWrappers.fitRModelFormula(SparkRWrappers.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:38)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInb
```

I really don't know how to fix it and when I got some kind of error they come from this RBackendHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] it was a problem generated when i tried to read the csv. I solve with this link:

> [R read.csv "More columns than column names" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771071/r-read-csv-more-columns-than-column-names-error)

Comment: Could you please entail what did you do to get ride of the error?

Comment: I think it  was generated by Blank value on csv that they were at the start of the document