# Error in Read.table, row.names are not allowed

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to read a csv file that I have in my AWS bucket.

I am using the below code to read the csv file. 
but I am getting a error,

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :    more columns than column names

I read the previous post to solve , but I was unsuccessful, could any one help me to resolve this issue.

The code I am using

```
library("aws.s3")
# using account credentials
aws.signature::use_credentials()
#Read Claim data
c<- get_object("s3://data-eu1/flexibleanalysislist/Data.csv")
#Convert object and show the data
cobj <-rawToChar(c)
con <- textConnection(cobj)
data<- read.csv(con)
```

Comment: maybe you can try passing in `header=FALSE` to take a look at your data. as the error msg mentions, you have more columns than column names

Comment: @chinsoon12    the error that I get now is "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input"

Comment: Add a sample (E.g. first 5 lines) of the csv file.

Comment: Did you take a look at the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771071/r-read-csv-more-columns-than-column-names-error/25771365) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311808/more-columns-than-column-names)? Not sure if it helps, but might be worth a try.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror , I simply changed the file name , and I was able to read the file :(

Comment: @lisah I looked at both .. and it works now, just by renaming my file

Comment: You might also try using `fread` (particularly the development version), which is much more robust in handling non-standard input .csv files